Physical interpretation of a dielectric's absorption curve
A given dielectric will behave as an absorbing medium for some frecuencies (those near one of the material's several resonant frequencies), whilst it will behave as a non-absorbing medium for the rest of them. This is shown in the following graph:

Although I understand the math behind of this curve, I can't seem to find a satisfactory Physical interpretation of why dielectrics behave this way, neither from a macroscopic nor a microscopic viewpoint.
